# Repairing windows 7 Raid 0

Tags: software-raid, raid-0

I have a raid 0 4 x1tb and 1x 3tb (a bit silly I know) but the partitions are now showing as RAW after I did a ckhdsk! is thair any raid reconfiguration software out there that will fix this? or is thair a quick fix so I can get all my data back?

Comment: You mean you used Raid 0 with no backup? crazy.

Answer (score 0):

As I have found out on my on skin, you cannot save a distroyed RAID 0 data. You better have a backup next time.